# Compare one element's x y coordinates to a list of elements to find a match (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a square 10x10 grid of divs with unique id's (say #square1, #square2 through #square100)

Each of these divs report their X and Y position in the the CSS.

Say:

```
…#square42 {left:20px; top:400px; width:10px; height:10px;}
#square43 {left:30px; top:400px; width:10px; height:10px;}...
```

What I am attempting to do is compare a separate selector's X and Y position on the page to the square divs listed out in the css. If that one selector has the same top/left value as one of the squares, then do something.

i.e.
if the x y of this div are

```
#squareElement {left:50px; top:70px;}
```

then I can add a style to this element's ID

```
#square75
```

Some pseudo code:
Get #squareElement top/left values, compare to #square1 through #square100, if equal then display that ID's inner paragraph tag.

Can anyone help me with some jQuery to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: We could, yes: can you help us by posting a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to work with? Make it easy for us to help you, and you'll get more/better responses. Incidentally, include the [relevant/sscce](http://sscce.org/) code in your question.

Comment: I have created a live demo for reference. It slightly differs from my pseudo example as it is a 9x9 box. http://jsfiddle.net/LL9cx/1/

My goal is to display the p tag of the div I am hovering over. Thank you!

Comment: Sry, I forgot to add the top/left values in the color ID's (that the JS X Y variables would compare themselves to), here is the updated - http://jsfiddle.net/LL9cx/2/  I appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do. The jsfiddle example seems quite different from your question. If you're trying to get positions of nodes, probably the easiest is something like

```
var pos = $('#square1').position();
console.log(pos.left, pos.top);
```

Or use something like

```
$('#square1').css('left);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! My question was confusing because I was confused. I ended up scratching this approach...